# Help regarding BizTalk

Tags: biztalk

i am having my biztalk solution, uptill now i am able to do following thing

1) taken sql adapter as my source schmea i wanted node wise xml so i did xml auto,elements in my SP to its generate schmea nodewise

2) i am able to loop through all the nodes and checking condition in loop wioth decide shape now decide shape is executing perfactly,but now the issue comes i want to insert my current xml into table,from all the xml nodes i am getting single node's xml like following

```
<userDetails xmlns="http://SqlRowLooping"><userID>1</userID><fName>niladri</fName><lName>Roy</lName><department>it</department></userDetails>
```

now i have updateGram as well but i think it will accept data attibutewise,right now it is firing error saying cant find procedure userID,

help how to insert this in table,

how updategram will work..

thxs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the XML node to conform to updategram syntax, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258669(SQL.80).aspx)